# Identify ProtoBuf class from byte array

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto

I am writing a program that works on two proto messages, I need to process the byte[] sent from different sources which sends either foo message or bar message. Since I cannot figure out which message it belongs to, I used Any Class (comes along with protobuf) to parse the byte array and 
find which class it belongs to, but met with a compile time error. Is there any other method that I can use to detect if I add more proto message classes in future?

```
//Foo.proto

syntax = "proto3";

option java_outer_classname = "FooProto";

message Foo {
    int32 a = 1;
}
```

and the second proto

```
//Bar.proto
syntax = "proto3";

option java_outer_classname = "BarProto";

message Bar {
    int32 b = 1;
}
```

Code:

```
Any anyEvent = Any.parseFrom(protoBytes);
if (any.is(Foo.class)
{
  Foo foo = any.unpack(Foo.class);
  ...
} else {
  Bar bar = any.unpack(Bar.class);
  ...
}
```

Error in if statement while trying to invoke any.is() :

> The method is(Class< T>) in the type Any is not applicable for the arguments (Class< Foo>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any` doesn't mean "any"; it means "a type serialized via Any". If you didn't *store* it with `Any`: you can't *decode* it via `Any`.

The key point here is that protobuf does not include type metadata in a message payload. If you have a BLOB, you usually *can't know* what the message type is. `Any` solves that by encoding the message type *in a wrapper message*, but you won't have that here.

---

If your design is to have an API that accepts two different non-`Any` message types without prior knowledge of which it is: you probably have a bad design. Because that *doesn't work* with protobuf. On the wire, there is *literally no difference* between a `Foo` with `a=42` and a `Bar` with `b=42`; the payloads **are identical**:

`Foo` with `a=42` is the bytes `08 2A`; `Bar` with `b=42` is the bytes `08 2A`. The `08` means "field 1, encoded as a varint", the `2A` is a varint with raw value 42.

A better design might be a wrapper message *specific to your scenario*:

```proto
message RootMessage {
  oneof test_oneof {
     Foo foo = 1;
     Bar bar = 2;
  }
}
```

This adds a wrapper layer *similar* to how `Any` works, but much more efficiently - it just knows how to distinguish between your known types as an integer, rather than having to handle every possible type (as a rooted type name).

Comment: Thanks for the info about Any, The problem is the foo message is produced from a source already and the design cannot be changed. Is there any other solution for it?

Comment: @Santosh is it just the two types as shown? In *that* scenario I might add an enum field (field 2) to Bar with a default of 0=Foo,1=Bar, and include that value with 1=Bar on the new producer - decode everything as a Bar, but if the enum field says Foo, interpret it as a Foo (just read the b and pretend it was an a). This only works because the field type is identical, though; if Foo has an int32 a=1 and Bar has a string b=1, it won't work.

Comment: @santosh the key thing to remember is that field names *don't matter* in the binary protocol; they aren't sent, and aren't used to decode; only the numbers matter (and their field types)

Comment: The data types defined are different from what I mentioned in the question, the field types wont match making it hard to identify the class it belongs to.

Comment: @Santhosh yup, that makes it very hard; your best bet, then, may be to use the "reader" API to inspect the payloads and see what fields and wire-types it has, to see if you can manually identify which is which; ultimately, protobuf isn't well-suited to what you're trying to do here - it *wants* to know the target type in advance

Comment: @Santhosh specifically: [CodedInputStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.html) - looks like `readTag()`, and `skipField()`; note that a "tag" is a composite of a field number and a wire-type using binary math (`{tag}={fieldNumber} << 3 | {wireType}`)